# Calling servlet from JSP pages

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem to call a servlet from My JSP pages. I have an error description

> The requested resource (/src/java/database/Reader) is not available.

this is My code on JSP pages

```
<form action="../../src/java/database/Reader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                                <label class="normal-label" for="choose-file">Upload data(.xls)</label>
                                <p></p>
                                <div class="file-input">
                                        <input type="file" id="choose-file" class="choose-file" name="spreadsheet" />
                                        <span class="button">- - - - -</span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="global-form-footer">
                <input class="btn-theme" id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
            </div>
            </form>
```

my servlet located on database package. Everyone, help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to configure your servlet mapping into web.xml and put your servlet classes into the /WEB-INF/classes folder which is default folder used by container for locating servlet classes.

Comment: I did it, but I can't move my servlet to WEB-INF/classes. I used Netbeans 6.9.1. what's wrong ?

Comment: First go through the article given by AVD.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go through articles suggested by @AVD but if you are looking for something quick here it is:

I recommend Eclipse when working with servlets and jsp

[1st] in your web.xml define and map your servlet. so include the following if it doesn't not exist.

> ```
> <servlet>
> <description>
> </description>
> <display-name>Reader</display-name>
> <servlet-name>Reader</servlet-name>
> <servlet-class>database.Reader</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
>
> <servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-name>Reader</servlet-name>
> <url-pattern>/Reader</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

[2nd] then on your form just post to Reader

> ```
> <form action="Reader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
> ...
> </form>
> ```

hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I go an error message **The requested resource (/ope_forex/Admin/Reader) is not available.** what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assign value of action in form tag as action="../../Reader"

In web.xml set url-pattern as /Reader and servlet-class as database.Reader

Answer (score 1):

you have to configure your servlet's `<url-pattern>` property in `web.xml` and then use that URL pattern in the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag.

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>java.database.Reader</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ReaderUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="ReaderUrl" method="post" ....
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but I go an error message **The requested resource (/ope_forex/Admin/Reader) is not available.** what's wrong?